# Is there any way to use Python to replace Flash for in browser animation, gaming, whatever?

Tags: web-development, python, web-applications

Is there any way to use Python to replace Flash for in browser animation, gaming, webapps, whatever?  Pretty straight-forward IMHO.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Simple, (1) create your own python based browser plugin, (2) market it heavily to increase market share (3) profit.

Comment: @pythagras: You make it sound so easy...it's tantalizing.

Comment: This has been asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540214/can-python-be-used-for-client-side-web-development

Comment: @Matt: I didn't think to search SO for this as this question contains no code.

Comment: I figured, that's why I answered anyways :)

Comment: Very indirect answer, but have you looked into the Unity engine (previously known as Unity3D)? It has a slight variant of Python you can use to program.

Comment: @Katana314, But Boo is not a “variant” of Python at all. It may be inspired by it, but it's different enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pythagras' comment is basically accurate.  Python is a server-side language, like PHP or C#.  Flash is a client-side language like JavaScript.  You'd need to create a Python plug-in or translator to use it client-side. Fortunately, someone else already has: check out [Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/).

Comment: IIUC Skulpt is an implementation of Python in Javascript, it is not a plug-in.

Comment: @Tony Meyer: Actually, it ought to be pretty simple to translate Skulpt into ActionScript, which means that you could run Python using the Flash plugin, and have all of that platform's features available. Um...So I'm just going to send a quick email to Mr. Graham...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [IronPython](http://ironpython.net) (an implementation of Python on .NET) to create [Silverlight](http://silverlight.net) applications.  Silverlight is a plug-in like Flash, and you can do essentially the same things with it (the installed base is smaller, although no-one really knows exactly what the numbers are).

Answer (score 1):

There is [Brython](http://www.brython.info), which is a browser-friendly Python(2.7+)-to-JavaScript compiler, written in JavaScript. It works pretty well already and has an active community.

With Brython, you can include your python scripts as simple as:

```
<script type="text/python"> ... </script>
```